# Jasmine how to put expectation on object returned from spied method

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I am trying to put an expectation on the number of times a certain function "upsertDocument" is called. In production, this method is part of a `DocumentClient` object returned by a `getClient` method. I.e

separate client.ts file:

```
getClient() {
    return new DocumentClient(...);
}
```

In the method I want to unit test:

```
import * as clientGetter from '../clients/client'
...
methodA(){
  ...
  client = clientGetter.getClient(); 
  for (...) {
    client.upsertDocument();
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `DocumentClient` constructor initializes an actual connection with the database, which obviously shouldn't happen in the unit tests. So I either need to spyOn the DocumentClient constructor, or on the getClient method, neither of which works.

If I spy on the DocumentClient constructor:

unit test:

```
it('does stuff', (done: DoneFn) => {
  spyOn(DocumentClient, 'prototype').and.returnValue({
    upsertDocument: () => {}
  })

  ...
})
```

I get the following error:

```
  Message:
    Error: <spyOn> : prototype is not declared writable or has no setter
    Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
  Stack:
    Error: <spyOn> : prototype is not declared writable or has no setter
    Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.fit (C:\Users\andalal\workspace\azure-iots-saas\service-cache-management\src\test\routes\managementRoute.spec.ts:99:35)
        at <Jasmine>
        at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
        at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
```

If I spy on the `getClient` method and return **my own** object, containing an `upsertDocument` method, I don't know how I can do an expectation on that mock object:

```
it('does stuff', (done: DoneFn) => {
  spyOn(clientGetter, 'getClient').and.returnValue({
    upsertDocument: () => {}
  })

  methodA().then(() => {
    expect().toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3); // what do I put in expect() ??
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this problem has already been addressed by an existing unit test, but I'll write a solution here that hopefully helps other people:

So the `getClient` method returns a DocumentClient that contains a certain list of methods. We don't want the actual DocumentClient constructor to be called. So we created a mock object that implemented the same interface as DocumentClient, and used `jasmine.createSpy` on each of the methods:

```
export class TestableDocumentClient implements IDocumentClient {
  upsertDocument = jasmine.createSpy('upsertDocument')
  ...
}
```

Then in my unit test, I spied on the `getClient` method and returned an object of the above type:

```
let mockDocClient = new TestableDocumentClient()
spyOn(clientGetter, getClient).and.returnValue(mockDocClient);

...

expect(mockDocClient.upsertDocument).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
```

For sanity's sake, I made a simple object that just had the method I wanted, and tried putting an expectation on that to see if it worked, and it did.

```
let myObj = {
  upsertDocument: jasmine.createSpy('upsertDocument')
}

spyOn(clientGetter, 'getClient').and.returnValue(myObj);

...
expect(myObj.upsertDocument).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
```